# How can I use Model Factories in October CMS?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

This is primarily for the sake of setting data up during testing; it appears that there is no official way in the documentation to get factories working as they do in the base Laravel Framework.  How can I instantiate them so that I could, for example, instantiate a set of models before running a test?

Comment: Couldn't find anything on this anywhere, save for a few forums posts of people asking how to do it (with no reply), so after figuring it out, I thought I should share it.

Answer (score 2):

In your base test file in the setUp method (or in your ServiceProvider if you need access to them outside of testing), you'll want to attach the the Eloquent Factory as a singleton to the container, which takes the Faker Generator and the path to the factory directory as arguments.

```
$this->app->singleton(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::class, function($app) {
    $faker = $app->make(Faker\Generator::class);
    return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::construct($faker, __DIR__.('/../path/to/factories/dir'));
});
```

Comment: Great. Thank you for sharing. For myself, I placed this code in PluginTestCase.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is also a snippet to add your factories in the plugin:
https://octoberduck.com/ru/article/factories-in-a-plugin

Place this code in your Plugin.php:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory as EloquentFactory;

public function register()
{
    app(EloquentFactory::class)->load(plugins_path('author/plugin/factories'));
}
```